# tkinter gui formatting menu's with frames (pyhon2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am currently a high school student taking a beginner programming class. We just started a new unit learning Tkinter in python and I had a few questions regarding a project we have. I decided to do my project on making a currency converter. I finished everything regarding api's, and now I've hit a road block when making my gui. I am having a problem moving my button around to desired locations. Currently my button is stuck in the middle, and if I change the rows and columns, it moves to random locations and ruins the white background. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks so much.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox

CURRENCY_CODES = ('USD','GDP')

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.setupUI()
        self.createWidgets()

    def setupUI(self):
        self.parent.title("User Input")
        self.grid()
        self.centerWindow()

    def centerWindow(self):
        app_width = 307
        app_height = 350

        sw = self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()
        sh = self.parent.winfo_screenheight()

        x = (sw - app_width)/2
        y = (sh - app_height)/2
        self.parent.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (app_width, app_height, x, y))

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.emptyFrame = tk.Frame(self.parent,bg="white")
        self.emptyFrame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="news")
        self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
```

Comment: Your `OptionMenu` (not a `Button`) is a child of `self.parent`, so `grid()`ing it at row/column 0 puts it right on top of `self.emptyFrame` which is set to the same location. If you `grid()` it somewhere else, it'll be in its own row/column in `self.parent`, which doesn't have a white background like `self.emptyFrame` does. You can make the menu widget a child of the frame, and then move it around the frame with `sticky`. If you want it in an arbitrary location, use `place()` as suggested in an answer.

Comment: your code doesn't show a button. It's hard to see what you're doing wrong when you don't include actual code.

Comment: Your title asks about formatting menus with frames, but your question is about organizing buttons in a window. Please change your title to something relevant to what is actually being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can chuck it anywhere you please with the 'x' & 'y' coordinates like so,

```
        self.currencyMenu.place(x = 10, y = 250)
```

Comment: because absolute positions for widgets are very difficult to manage. You have to do all the math yourself. If you add another widget, or decide to change the size of the main widget, you have to go back and fiddle with the placement of every single widget. Plus, if the code runs in a different resolution or with different fonts, things may not line up properly. If the user resizes the window they may not line up properly either (and you should always allow the user to resize the window). `grid` and `pack` take care of all of those problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't show a complete program, nor does it show any buttons, so it's impossible to tell you all the problems. However, you're doing a couple of things that are definitely leading you down the wrong path.

The first problem is this:

```
self.grid()
```

As a general rule, the function that creates a widget is the function that should add the widget with a geometry manager. Wherever you call `Application()` should be responsible for putting the frame in its container.

```
app = Application(root)
app.grid(...)
```

Second, is this line of code:

```
self.emptyFrame = tk.Frame(self.parent,bg="white")
```

A child of a frame or root window (which is what `Application` is) should never put widgets outside of itself. Everything inside of `Application` should be literally inside of `Application`. Otherwise it becomes impossible to juggle all of the geometry management. That empty frame needs to be inside of `Application` (eg: `self`):

```
self.emptyFrame = tk.Frame(self, bg="white")
```

If you have a class that inherits from some other widget class, it should only ever affect itself and it's children<sup>1</sup>. It should never do anything that affects its parent.  If you stick to that principle, widget layout becomes much, much, *much* easier.

<sup>1</sup> I realize there are many examples on the internet that violate this principle, but they are all doing it wrong. While it's more-or-less OK for trivial applications, it quickly becomes quite a burden with complex applications. If you practice proper coding on the simple apps, then you won't have to change your technique when you graduate to more complex apps.